# XMLGregorianCalendar to String conversion error

Tags: java, simpledateformat, gregorian-calendar

The following code snippet works perfectly for dates with year above `1600` or so. But it gives wrong output for years like `1001, 1500, 1400` etc. Can you explain why?

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

XMLGregorianCalendar cal DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("1600-01-01");

String birthDate = format.format(cal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());

System.out.println(birthDate);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong? Please give an example what is printed and what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure the Gregorian Calender started in the year 1582 which would explain why it works for 1600 but not for 1500.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the DateFormat displaying the 'wrong' year after converting the XMLGregorianCalendar to a [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) is the fact that GregorianCalendar.getGregorianChange() defaults to 1582-10-15.

If the GregorianCalendar is set to a date before the Gregorian Calendar change date, it will actually be representing dates in the [Julian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar), which results in the year appearing to be 'wrong', because the length of a year is different for these two calendars.

A fix for this could be using GregorianCalendar.setGregorianChange() to set this value to an earlier date in order to avoid it changing to the Julian calendar.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not pretty sure. But I think that it refers to Epoch (date), but... epoch starts in 1970 (not 1960).

Also Gregorian Calendar has some limitations (I can't mention each one, but..), for example, You can't use a date from 'zero' year, this can not interpreted correctly (I think Date is out of Anno Domini, and instead you should refer to Before Christ... I'm not sure).

However... You should look around for "epoch". And I hope this could be useful to find the right answer.